# Creating an array in objective c which is available to all the objects of the class in which array is created

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I want to create an array that is to be initialized when a function ( e.g. FillArray() ) of the class is called. After the function FillArray() will never be called.

I want that this array is available to all other objects of the class once it is initialized.

How can I do that. Thanks is advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simple declare a static array like this!

```
static NSMutableArray *staticArray = nil;

void FillArray() {
    if(staticArray == nil) {
        staticArray = [[NSMutableArray aloc] init];
    }
}
```

and when you no loner need it! remember to release it!

```
void FreeArray() {
    [staticArray release];
    staticArray = nil;
}
```

Comment: Note that unless you're using ARC this is not thread-safe; you'll need to do appropriate mutual exclusion (e.g. NSLock, @synchronize, dispatch_sync) or use something like dispatch_once or pthread_once.  Even with ARC, if it's expensive to initialise your array (or it has side-effects) you'll need to do mutual exclusion regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Make it static / shared / global.

@implementation MySingleton
static NSMutableArray *_sharedMySingletonArray = nil;

```
+(MySingleton*)sharedMySingleton
{
    @synchronized([MySingleton class])
    {
        if (!_sharedMySingletonArray)
            [[self alloc] init];

        return _sharedMySingletonArray;
    }

    return nil;
}
@end
```

Comment: can u give some example for making an array as static. I am not able to do that